# struts 2 --> checkbox seems to have issue when next page and then previous page

Tags: java, struts2

I have the struts2 checkbox which behavior strangely when there are previous and next paging situation. 
I have the three pages jsp named step1.jsp, step2.jsp and step3.jsp 
I have the checkbox control on step1.jsp.

```
<s:checkbox value="%{loanForm.directmarketingCheckboxboolean}" name="loanForm.directmarketingCheckboxboolean"
                    style="vertical-align:middle;" id="directmarketingCheckbox" />

private boolean directmarketingCheckboxboolean;
public boolean isDirectmarketingCheckboxboolean() {
        return directmarketingCheckboxboolean;
    }
public void setDirectmarketingCheckboxboolean(boolean directmarketingCheckboxboolean) {
        this.directmarketingCheckboxboolean = directmarketingCheckboxboolean;
    }
```

1. Load step1.jsp and checked the checkbox in step1 and clicked next button. It goes to step2.jsp.
2. In step2.jsp, click previous button. It goes to step1.jsp.
3. The checkbox in step 1 is checked. Then I unchecked it and click
   next button.  It goes to step2.jsp.
4. In step2.jsp, click previous button. It goes to step1.jsp.
5. The checkbox in step1 is still checked. (It should show unchecked.
   Right?).

[first step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwr26.png)

[second time after next and previous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7oWZ.png)

[third time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5oXP.png)

According to the your request, I post my page (display_loan_step2) here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>


<%
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
    %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Loan Application Step 2</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<s:head />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./js/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
    <s:form action="LoanFormResult3" namespace="/" theme="simple" cssClass="well form-search">

            <p>
                <s:checkbox value="%{loanForm.directmarketingCheckboxboolean}" name="loanForm.directmarketingCheckboxboolean"
                    style="vertical-align:middle;" id="directmarketingCheckbox" />
                <s:text name="label.directmarketing.remark2" />
            </p>


    <s:url action="LoanFormResult.action" var="urlPrev" >
        <s:param name="name">previous</s:param>
    </s:url>

    <s:a href="%{urlPrev}" cssClass="btn btn-primary" id="btnPrevious">Previous</s:a>
    <s:submit key="submit" cssClass="btn btn-primary" id="btnNext" value="Next">
        <s:hidden name="name" value="next"/>
    </s:submit>

    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="cardAppPublic" extends="struts-default">
        <action 
            name="LoanFormResult" method="displayPrevious" class="loanActionForm">
            <result name="display_loan_step1">/WEB-INF/jsp/display_loan_step1.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action 
            name="LoanFormResult2" method="display" class="loanActionForm">
            <result name="display_loan_step2">/WEB-INF/jsp/display_loan_step2.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action 
            name="LoanFormResult3" method="displayNext" class="loanActionForm">
            <result name="display_loan_step3">/WEB-INF/jsp/display_loan_step3.jsp</result>
        </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

Whole backend code:

```
public class LoanAction extends ActionSupport{
    private LoanForm loanForm;
    public LoanForm getLoanForm() {
            return (LoanForm) ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("loanForm");
        }
    public void setLoanForm(LoanForm loanForm) {
            ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put("loanForm", loanForm);
        }
    public String display(){

    return "display_loan_step2";
    }

    public String displayNext(){

    return "display_loan_step3";
    }
    public String displayPrevious(){

    return "display_loan_step1";
    }
}

public class LoanForm extends ActionSupport{
    private boolean directmarketingCheckboxboolean;
    public boolean isDirectmarketingCheckboxboolean() {
            return directmarketingCheckboxboolean;
        }
    public void setDirectmarketingCheckboxboolean(boolean directmarketingCheckboxboolean) {
            this.directmarketingCheckboxboolean = directmarketingCheckboxboolean;
        }
}
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="loanActionForm" class="com.struts.action.LoanAction" />

</beans>
```

Comment: no, it's not true.

Comment: I have posted my page code

Comment: `LoanForm` shouldn't be an action. Action should be prototype. Tag `value` attribute is for presetting data.